# Can I use RL Expo to update the app in the App Store and revert to the previous version?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play, app-store

I'm working on maintaining the React Native app. This app is now distributed in the App Store and Google Store and I am going to update this app using `expo publish`.

It's my first time distributing an app.
After updating the app, if there is a problem with this app, can I revert to the previous version of the app in the App Store and Google Store?